# How to make select all row using code in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable for listing some users
I would like to select all rows using a function call.
Is there any way ?
I am using angular 4

Answer (score 5):

Edit 1

My old answer had a few negative side effects and I took time to dig around a bit more. As I understand, since you can only tick a select all button in the header, there is a onHeaderSelect() function under DatatableComponent and if we externally trigger it, it functions as a select all checkbox click.

Code below.

```
export class DatatableVerticalComponent implements OnInit {

    public rows = [{prop1:1, prop2:2},{prop1:3, prop2:4}];

    @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) ngxDatatable: DatatableComponent;

    onSelectAllClick() {
        this.ngxDatatable.onHeaderSelect(true);
    }

}
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

Since I removed the header row and thus could not use the default checkbox functionality

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#chkbox-selection

I made a quick workaround to select all rows, from outside of the ngx-datatable.

Code:

```
export class DatatableVerticalComponent implements OnInit {

    public rows = [{prop1:1, prop2:2},{prop1:3, prop2:4}];

    @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) ngxDatatable: DatatableComponent;

    onSelectAllClick() {
        this.ngxDatatable.selected = this.rows;
    }

}
```

Explanation:

First you take the  as a ViewChild in the component.ts file. Now ngx-datatable keeps the selected rows as an array

```
/**
   * List of row objects that should be
   * represented as selected in the grid.
   * Default value: `[]`
   */
@Input() selected: any[] = [];
```

Since I did not find a function to set selected rows in the DatatableComponent, I just used the ViewChild to set the selected variable. I did not create data-binding with [@Input], because I do not want to leave the impression that I am constantly controlling the selection from outside code.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have your users stored in `users` prop, you'll need to add `selected` input prop to your table in template like this:

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="users" [selected]="selectedUsers">...
```

After that, you should be able to select all users in your component logic like this:

```
@Component()
export class UsersComponent {
  users: any[];
  selectedUsers: any[];

  /* ... */

  selectAllUsers(): void {
    this.selectedUsers = [...users];
  }
}
```

Please note this approach is very simplified just to give you an idea of what possible solution might look like. That means it hasn't been tested, so let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but I had the same issue and think sharing my solution could help.

Based on the code of ngxdatatable ([github source](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/projects/swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/lib/components/datatable.component.ts#L1088) - I add the snippet as well as the link may become obsolete with code changes):

```
  /**
  * Toggle all row selection
  */
  onHeaderSelect(event: any): void {
    if (this.selectAllRowsOnPage) {
      // before we splice, chk if we currently have all selected
      const first = this.bodyComponent.indexes.first;
      const last = this.bodyComponent.indexes.last;
      const allSelected = this.selected.length === last - first;

      // remove all existing either way
      this.selected = [];

      // do the opposite here
      if (!allSelected) {
        this.selected.push(...this._internalRows.slice(first, last));
      }
    } else {
      // before we splice, chk if we currently have all selected
      const allSelected = this.selected.length === this.rows.length;
      // remove all existing either way
      this.selected = [];
      // do the opposite here
      if (!allSelected) {
        this.selected.push(...this.rows);
      }
    }

    this.select.emit({
      selected: this.selected
    });
  }
```

**The onHeaderSelect toggles all row selection which is not what I need.**

**I need to select all rows.**

Therefore, inspired by the code source I just wrote the below method in my component:

```
 @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) ngxDatatable: DatatableComponent;

 ...

 unselectRows(): void {
    const table = this.ngxDatatable;
    const allSelected = table.selected.length === table.rows.length;
    if (!allSelected) {  // Select all only if not already the case
      // Reset the selection first
      table.selected = [];
      // Add all rows to the selection
      table.selected.push(...table.rows);
      // Important: Emit the select event
      table.select.emit({
        selected: table.selected
      });
    }
  }
```

This solution works fine for my use case.

**Note**: I do not use `selectAllRowsOnPage` which may induce issue(s) I did not handle here.